# Cannot set __cplusplus to C++17 standard with Visual Studio and CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I've a CMake project that's opened with Visual Studio 2019. I need c++17 features for my code, so I've set the corresponding flag in the `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10.0)

project (datalog)

message (STATUS "Building project ${PROJECT_NAME}")

find_package(stxxl CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

set (PROJECT_SRC
  main.cpp
  )

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRC})
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} stxxl)
```

When I build I obtain a lot of errors, because the library that I'm linking, `stxxl`, installed with `vcpkg`, has the following piece of code:

```
STXXL_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

template <class Type>
struct compat_unique_ptr {
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L && ((__GNUC__ * 10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100) >= 40400)
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Type> result;
#else
    // auto_ptr is inherently broken and is deprecated by unique_ptr in c++0x
    typedef std::auto_ptr<Type> result;
#endif
};

STXXL_END_NAMESPACE
```

The problem is that `__cplusplus` has value `199711L` instead of the correct value [`201703L`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2019), so code tries to use `auto_ptr` that's removed in C++17 standard.

I've also tried to set the flag manually in Visual Studio, adding this section in the `CmakeLists.txt`

```
if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++17 /Zc:__cplusplus")
endif()
```

But nothing changes. I'm also using some C++17 features, so going back at the moment is not an option.

I can manually update the `stxxl` header file to get rid of the macro, but it's a workaround, and every developer should create the same fix. Instead, I'd like to know why I'm getting the error and how to set the macro to the correct value with Visual Studio and CMake. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Visual Studio does not support all C++17 features. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Comment: Please see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/

Comment: @JesperJuhl I did it and I've tried to set the `/Zc` flag as written in that article, as I've said in my post, but nothing changes. Maybe I need to set Visual Switches in another way?

Comment: Note that you'll have to hack the header anyway, as even if you get MSVC to set the correct `__cplusplus`, you're unlikely to make it set `__GNUC__`.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed it and I'm creating a pull request in vcpkg repository, but the `__cplusplus` problem remain, that's a general problem and not strictly related to the library.

Comment: Have you tried `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`? Have a look [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html#variable:CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD).

Answer (score 8):

As far as i can tell from [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18837), you need to add `/Zc:__cplusplus` manually (at least for now).

Your CMakeList snippet worked for me, are you sure, that `__cplusplus` is actually set incorrectly and it's not just the `__GNUC__` Macro, that's missing?

That said, I'd recommend to test if the version of VisualStudio is actually new enough:

```
# /Zc:__cplusplus is required to make __cplusplus accurate
# /Zc:__cplusplus is available starting with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7
# (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus)
# That version is equivalent to _MSC_VER==1914
# (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019)
# CMake's ${MSVC_VERSION} is equivalent to _MSC_VER
# (according to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/MSVC_VERSION.html#variable:MSVC_VERSION)
if ((MSVC) AND (MSVC_VERSION GREATER_EQUAL 1914))
    target_compile_options(stxxl INTERFACE "/Zc:__cplusplus")
endif()
```

Note: I used [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) to add the necessary option to the interface of your library target. This way all targets, that depend on that library (via target_link_libraries) will be compiled with that flag, but targets, that don't need it (and might be incompatible with it) won't get it.

If you want to add the flag to one of your own targets, you can use `target_compile_options(stxxl PUBLIC "/Zc:__cplusplus")` (`PUBLIC` instead of `INTERFACE`). `INTERFACE` means the option is used when other targets depend on that target, `PRIVATE` means the option is used for the target itself and `PUBLIC` means both. (IMHO [this artical](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/#build-requirements-vs-usage-requirements) explains it well.)

---

Apart from that, you shouldn't set the c++ standard version via compile flags, but instead using [target_compile_features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#requiring-language-standards) if the newer version is required and using
[`set_target_properties(your_target_name PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) if you just wish to use the newer version if it is available.

In your case the latter is probably sufficient as your codesnippet has a fallback if the c++ version is older.

---

If changing the code of stxxl (via pull request, etc.) is an option, the code could test [`_MSVC_LANG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros) and [`_MSC_VER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros). This way it would work without requiring `/Zc:__cplusplus`.

Answer (score -2):

I think what you need is [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html), where you can define arbitrary macros in CMake and pass to compiler.