# What conditional compilation is needed around C++ attributes?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

I'm starting to add `[[nodiscard]]`, `[[noreturn]]` and `[[fallthrough]]` to my code base, but I still worry the code might need to be used on an older C++ version.

I'm only worried about g++, clang, and Visual Studio.

To be safe should I make every single usage depend on a version check for the exact version it appeared?  Or, do these compilers accept (or does the spec even mandate they accept) any `[[`attribute`]]` even if unknown, starting with C++11?

Were these allowed and ignored (or supported) even before C++11?  (I ask not what the spec says but what the software actually did.)

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
#define MyNamespace_NoReturnCPP17 [[noreturn]]
#else
#define MyNamespace_NoReturnCPP17
#endif
```

(Off subject but if I were on the C++ committee, I'd re-use the `case` keyword to do the same thing as `switch`, when followed by `(`, except it would in effect have an automatic `break` before each `case` label.  And within the `case`'s block (and nowhere else), `fallthrough` would be accepted as a keyword, that suppresses that automatic `break`.)

I note the C++14 spec 7.6.1.5 says behavior is "implemenation-defined" but I'm asking a more practical question about what compilers actually did.  https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf

The C++17 spec 10.6.1.6 says "Any attribute-token that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored."  That answers my question for C++17 and newer, but again my question is about earlier compilers.  https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf

Comment: Which compilers are you targeting? Because checking [`__cplusplus` is not always a good choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57102212/332733). So what you're trying to do is a lot more complicated than it seems. If your minimum is C++17 then just call it that and work around where and when you need to and don't waste time and effort otherwise.

Comment: *"but I still worry the code might need to be used on an older C++ version"* - Because there's an actual potential consumer of your code using an "older" version? How much "older" are we talking about? C++17 is itself 5 years old now, a good while in IT terms.

Comment: There is literally no limit on how quirky older compilers can be.  But I do know that compilers often claim `__cplusplus` without a perfect feature match.  I know boost has extensive compiler version detection based macros, I'd consider looking at what it does.

Answer (score 1):

> To be safe should I make every single usage depend on a version check for the exact version it appeared? Or, do these compilers accept (or does the spec even mandate they accept) any [[attribute]] even if unknown, starting with C++11?

I prefer adding version checks for safety although mainstream compilers will throw a warning for unknown attributes.

- gcc [`-Wno-ignored-attributes` / `-Wattributes`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)
- Clang [`-Wunknown-attributes`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wunknown-attributes)
- MSVC [`C5030`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warnings-c4800-through-c4999?view=msvc-170)

I'm not sure these warning options(and corresponding behavior) have been added since the first C++11 feature-complete version, so you'd better do some checks.

> Were these allowed and ignored (or supported) even before C++11?

Since standard attributes syntax is supported starting from C++11, compilers will have trouble at the parsing stage. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4nbTf5sj7)